# php как правильно сделать что при каком либо insert в базе сохранялось время этого insert

Tags: php

php как правильно сделать что при каком либо insert в базе сохранялось время этого insert

Comment: В структуру таблицы следует добавить поле `created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и не упоминать его в запросе на вставку вообще - значение, равное текущему штампу времени на MySQL-сервере, будет присвоено автоматически. См. [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html). Если записи могут быть изменены, полезно также добавить и поле `updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.